# Set focus on a text box in ember js

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to change a text to a text box. If a user clicks the text, it will change to a test box and so they can edit the content. I have done that. I am able to set the focus by below code.

```
{{input value=animal.name autofocus=true}}
```

It only works for the first time. If I focus-out, the text box will again change to text content. If I click the text again, I am able to see the text box, but it is not in focus. Below is the code I am trying.

Component file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  isTextBox: false,
  actions: {
    editTest() {
      this.set('isTextBox', true);
    }
  },
  focusOut() {
    this.set('isTextBox', false);
  },
});
```

Template file:

```
{{yield}}
<center><h2>
<div onclick = {{action 'editTest'}}>
{{#if isTextBox}}
{{input value=animal.name autofocus=true}}
{{else}}
{{animal.name}}
{{/if}}
</div>
</h2></center>
```

I am new to ember and I trying to do the focus without using jQuery.

Here is the twiddle https://ember-twiddle.com/d832c6540ba94901a6c42d5bb3cfa65e?openFiles=templates.components.text-input.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.text-input.hbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide id to input helper,

```
{{input id='cat-text' value=animal.name }}
```

You can make it focus text field for every rendering,

```
didRender(){    
    this.$('#cat-text').focus();
  }
```

Comment: Is this `this.$('#cat-text').focus();` jQuery function?  Is there any other way without using jQuery function? (Is there any ember function available?). Using a jQuery function within ember is recommended one?

Comment: I didn't fix this after finding the root cause. I just fixed it to get what you need. Using jQuery function is not at all recommended one. by the way dont accept this answer as acceptable since there might be ember way of fixing this issue which i am not aware of.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in Plain Old Javascript as follows:

```
didRender(){
    // This works but is not very ember-ish
    // document.getElementById('cat-text').focus();

    // For a component, you can do this
    this.get('element').querySelector("#cat-text").focus();
}
```

This assumes you have an input like this:

```
{{input id='cat-text' value=animal.name }}
```

Ember 2.13+ is no longer dependent on jQuery (although some of the add-ons that you use may be), so you have the possibility of eliminating 35kb (min + gzip) that jQuery would add to the payload of your app.

Comment: Please note that if this component have an input field, and if user types in it, it calls the `didRender` function again and user loses the focus on input. I have changed it to `didInsertElement`

Answer (score 2):

To expand on kumkanillam's answer you can just set the focus at the end of the render lifecycle if it's rendering a textbox. Since you've only got one text input in your component you can just find it with a selector. No need to worry about using jQuery here that's what it's there for so it is the Ember way.

```
didRender(){
  if(this.get('isTextBox')){
    this.$('input[type=text]:first').focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I am worried about using the jQuery inside the ember. Your comments clearly say we can use it.

Answer (score 0):

components/input-text-focused/component.js:

```
import TextField from '@ember/component/text-field';

export default TextField.extend({
  didInsertElement(...args) {
    this._super(...args);
    const element = this.get('element');
    if (element) element.focus();
  },
});
```

```
{{input-text-focused type="text" name="search" value=search}}
```